# invalid runtime value go when trying to deplay a proxy app

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, google-app-engine-golang

I'm trying to deploy my direction app in Google Cloud Console using the terminal with:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

But I get this error:

```
peter@cloudshell:~/direction-proxy (myapp-3f67k)$ gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Staging command [/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/go-app-stager /home/peter/direction-proxy/app.yaml /home/peter/direction-proxy /tmp/tmpw9zlbhhe/tmp74n__vq4] failed with return code [1].
------------------------------------ STDOUT ------------------------------------
------------------------------------ STDERR ------------------------------------
2020/06/19 13:08:51 invalid runtime value go
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my app.yaml file that I think it produces this error but I have hard times understanding. I'm very new to Go.

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
  login: admin
```

Comment: Migrate the application to runtime `go11` or later.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences for info on how to migrate the application.  The most recent runtime is `go113`.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime.

Comment: @MuffinTop If I check the version using `go version` I get `go1.13 linux/amd64`. Is that migration to 1.11 sufficient?

Comment: Because you  are using Go version 1.13 in your local development environment, I would think that you want to use the `go113` runtime on App Engine.  Follow the migration instructions linked from my previous comment.  Edit the app.yaml to specify `runtime: go113`.

Comment: @MuffinTop No, I'm using only the online version.

Comment: Your local environment is the place where you are typing commands like `gcloud app deploy` and `go version`.